# Creating a dynamic array show only the last

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of links similar to below:

```
<a href="array_add.php?n=1">1</a>
<a href="array_add.php?n=2">2</a>
<a href="array_add.php?n=3">3</a>
<a href="array_add.php?n=4">4</a>
```

And the `array_add.php` is :

```
$myarray = array();
$number = $_GET['n'];
$myarray[] = $number;
var_dump($myarray);
```

But the above var_dump displays only the last number received from GET. But I need an array of the numbers clicked.

Comment: `Session` or may be `Cookies` will suits for this

Comment: You know HTTP is a stateless protocol , also all those anchor elements are orphans and they are not interlinked or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['myarray'])) {
   $myarray = $_SESSION['myarray'];
} else {
   $myarray = array();
}
if (isset($_GET['n'])) {
   $number = $_GET['n'];
   $myarray[] = $number;
   $_SESSION['myarray'] = $myarray;
}
```